Calculated column by combining 2 other columns where column A is ref column has duplicate distinct values
Calculated column by combining 2 other columns where column A is ref column has duplicate distinct values. If column B has result any row for that specific Ref in column then same should be the result and will not overwrite the column C if any row is blank from column B. If column B is blank for all ref as per column A then column C result should come in end result.



Column A
Column B
Column C




India




China
T1



India
T2
T3


China

T4


Russia

T3


Russia




Rome
T2



Japan
T1



Rome




Japan

T3






Column A
Column B
Column C
Result




India





China
T1

T1


India
T2
T3
T2


China

T4



Russia

T3
T3


Russia
T0




Rome
T2

T2


Japan
T1

T1


Rome





Japan

T3





Please guys. sorry but i am in hurry

Column B for Russia is blank, apologies for typo

on the table view create a column with an IF statement so if column B is blank use column C
Result = IF(NOT(ISBLANK(TableName[ColumnB])), TableName[ColumnB], TableName[ColumnC])

